# Is there a way for a remote validation attribute to fire when either field is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

So the problem I am facing is that the Remote attribute I have created only fires when the field it is declared on changes. But I need it to fire when either is changed.

```
class MyViewModel

[Remote("ValidateTwoFields", "ControllerName", AdditionalFields = "Field2", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Errors_SomeErrorMessageThatShouldBeShowOnce", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]

public string Field1{ get; set; }

public string Field2{ get; set; }
```

In Controller:

```
//this only gets called when Field1 changes
//If I put the remote attribute on Field2 as well it displays the error message twice
public JsonResult ValidateTwoFields(MyViewModel model)
{

}
```

Comment: I've dealt with a similar issue before and the way I handled it was using a bit of javascript on the second field (i.e. handling a few events and triggering the validation).  Hopefully someone else has an easier solution.

Comment: What about setting your attribute to the second field as well and set AdditionalFields to Field1 on that?

Comment: This leads to the message being displayed twice, and the error message for the first doesn't disappear when the second is changed. They are treated as separate instances.

Comment: Figuring the options might be 1) Roll my own attribute that supports AllowMultiple or 2) Javascript client side to manually trigger it

Comment: appclay could you post your solution for this?

Comment: Unobtrusive MVC validations are limited to a single value by design (they only take a single value argument) so if you want to validate multiple related fields you'll probably need to roll your own

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but could it possibly be solved by lumping the two fields into a class containing two strings, and adding the validation on the one class?